# Derivative of a Fock state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space

Let us suppose we have the operators $a(\omega)$ and $a^\dagger(\omega)$ with $[a(\omega),a^\dagger (\omega')] = \delta(\omega-\omega')$. Does a derivative of the Fock state $a^\dagger(\omega) |0\rangle$ with respect to $\omega$ exist, that is $\partial_{\omega} a^\dagger(\omega) |0\rangle $. Or more generally, do these expressions make senes
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\omega} a^\dagger(\omega)\\
\partial_{\omega} a(\omega)
\end{equation}
Intuitively, I would guess that the derivative does not exist because of the orthogonality of Fock states for different $\omega$. But maybe the derivative can be expressed in terms of a delta function.

My idea to find an expression for the derivative is the following. First let us rewrite the annihilation operator as
\begin{equation}
a(\omega) = \int d\omega' \delta (\omega' - \omega) a(\omega').
\end{equation}
Differentiation of the above expression with $\partial_{\omega}\delta (\omega' - \omega) = -\delta' (\omega'-\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega'-\omega} \delta (\omega' - \omega)$ yields
\begin{equation}
\partial_{\omega}a(\omega) = \int d\omega' \partial_{\omega}\delta (\omega' - \omega) a(\omega') = \frac{1}{\omega-\omega} a(\omega) .
\end{equation}
So one could argue that the derivative does not exist or that is equals $\infty$, is that correct?

Comment: What are these freaky pseudoidentities displayed in your inline differentiation?

Comment: I am not sure if those identities are correct, but first I use the chain rule $\partial_{\omega} \delta (\omega' - \omega) = - \omega \delta ' (\omega' - \omega)$, then I use the fact that $\delta' (x) = - \frac{1}{x} \delta (x)$

Comment: No, you misapply the chain rule and these are not correct identities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quantum field theory deriving operators with respect to parameters is routine. (Recall how the canonical momentum field is produced.)

So, if you are careful, of course you may define such objects.
For instance,
$[a(\omega),a^\dagger (\omega')] = \delta(\omega-\omega')$ can yield
$$[\partial_{\omega} a(\omega),a^\dagger (\omega')] = \partial_{\omega} \delta(\omega-\omega').$$

Given the identity
$$
(\partial_{\omega} + \partial_{\omega’})\delta(\omega-\omega')=0,
$$
you then see that. e.g.,
$$
[\partial_{\omega} a(\omega),\int\!\! d\omega'~ f(\omega')~a^\dagger (\omega')] = \int\!\! d\omega'~ f(\omega')~ \partial_{\omega} \delta(\omega-\omega')\\ = -\int\!\! d\omega'~ f(\omega')~ \partial_{\omega'} \delta(\omega-\omega') = \int\!\! d\omega'~\partial_{\omega'}  f(\omega')~ \delta(\omega-\omega') = f'(\omega).$$

*NB Response to comment ancillary question*  Yes, of course. Since
$$\partial_x a(\omega/x)= -{\omega \over x} \partial_\omega a(\omega/x),$$
and analogously for $a^\dagger (\omega'/x)$, you indeed have, obviously,
$$
[\partial_x a(\omega/x) , \partial_x a^\dagger (\omega'/x)]={\omega \omega' \over x^2}\partial_\omega \partial_{\omega '} [ a(\omega/x) ,   a^\dagger (\omega'/x)]= -{\omega \omega ' \over x}\partial^2_\omega \delta (\omega-\omega').
$$

Comment: Should one of the derivatives in the second expression have a prime?

Comment: Thanks. Of course!

Comment: Any idea what the value of $[\partial_x a(\omega /x), \partial_x a^\dagger (\omega' /x) ]$ could be? Is it $[\partial_x a(\omega /x), \partial_x a^\dagger (\omega' /x) ] = - \frac{\omega \omega'}{x} \partial_{\omega}^2 \delta (\omega - \omega')$ ?